# Inversion in interrogative questions

Tags: inversion, fronting

In indirect questions, the so-called *penthouse principle* disallows *Subject-AV inversion.*

Thus,

> Cathy wonders what did Sam eat. (Incorrect)

> Cathy wonders what Sam ate. (Correct)

What is the rule for a sentence like this?

> Might I know **who that person is**?

> Might I know **who is that person**? (Incorrect)

The above sentence admits of inversion. I can see it has an embedded interrogative clause within the matrix clause (the whole sentence).

Why is there no inversion in the matrix clause but inversion in the embedded clause?

Comment: Because "the rules are different if you live in the penthouse" - main and subordinate clauses are just treated differently when inversion takes place.

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko Could you please elaborate on that? You're merely rephrasing the penthouse principle. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct clause in these sentences has the question word at the front but no verbal inversion

> Sam ate (something)

> What Sam ate.

The word "what" is moved up to the front of the clause, but the subject (Sam) still precedes the verb (ate).

To form a standalone question you also have to invert the verb

> What Same ate ->  What Sam did eat [do support] -> What did Sam eat.  [inversion].

Your "penthouse principle" doesn't allow for this inversion, so "Might I know what did Sam eat" is incorrect (though understandable)

But "is" doesnt need do support. So

> That person is (someone)

> Who that person is

The word "who" is moved up to the front of the clause, but the subject (that person) still precedes the verb (is).

To form a standalone question you also have to invert the verb

> Who that person is -> who is that person

Your "penthouse principle" doesn't allow for this inversion, so "Might I know who is that person" is incorrect (though understandable)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @James K. I don't if this my asking you this makes any sense, but why does this so-called _penthouse principle_ restrict us to construct such sentences? Is it some sacred cow of grammar or what?

Comment: No, its is just a tendency, and not one specific to English.  For example in German, the main clause is subject-Verb-Object, but subordinate clause are Subject-object-verb.  There are other examples in other languages.  So this is an observed tendency, rather than a strict law.

Comment: Could you please suggest further literature (available online) on fronting and inversion? @James K.

Comment: bbc has something https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/course/towards-advanced/unit-25/session-1

Comment: Thanks a lot, @James K.